# Update UI Thread from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, backgroundworker

I am trying to execute the simple action of updating a progress bar on my UI inside of a loop by using a `BackgroundWorker`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void ProcessButtonClickAction(object param)
{
   BackgroundWorker BGWUpdateUi = new BackgroundWorker();

   BGWUpdateUi.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
   {
       ProgressBarValue += args.ProgressPercentage;
       ((SelectedDwgFile)args.UserState).Status = "Completed";
   };

   BGWUpdateUi.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    foreach(var obj in FileList)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        BGWUpdateUi.ReportProgress(pbvalueIncrement, obj);
    }
}
```

The collection is an `ObservableCollection` and `ProgressBarValue` is bound to the value of the progress bar.

I have looked at several of examples and no matter which one I try - `BackgroundWorker`, `Dispatcher` - they all update after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the part that you want to run in the background, into the `DoWork` method, and then call `RunWorkerAsync`:

```
private void ProcessButtonClickAction(object param)
{
   BackgroundWorker BGWUpdateUi = new BackgroundWorker()

   BGWUpdateUi.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
   {
       foreach (var obj in FileList)
       {
           Thread.Sleep(250);
           obj.Status = "Completed";
           ProgressBarValue += pbvalueIncrement;
       }
   };
   BGWUpdateUi.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

<s>Also, make sure to dispatch UI-related updates back to the UI thread (otherwise you will get a cross-thread access exception).</s>

Comment: I guess, I'm not understanding. I want to be in a loop and after i execute some logic, I want to update the UI. Do i have to execute the logic in the DoWork event?

Comment: @TraeMoore yes, you have to put it in `DoWork`, otherwise it will execute synchronously, and the UI won't get updated until the end of the method.

Comment: Im sorry, I must be driving you crazy. :) I am executing this from an ICommand, So i do not have access to Application. My ViewModel is completely separated from my view. and FileList is binded to a `DataGrid` so i can not push it `ToArray()`.

Comment: @TraeMoore no, no worries ... I'm barely awake, this is helping me wake up :P.  `Application` should be a static class, so you must have access to it?  Actually though, try without the dispatcher -- it seems to work, although I don't understand why.

Comment: @TraeMoore as far as FileList ... I don't know, maybe try without that.  I thought you couldn't access UI stuff from a background thread, but maybe I was mistaken...

Comment: @TraeMoore yes, for sure.